# Completed property in Angular Material Stepper doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: angular-material

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-horizontal-stepper-3i5s1j?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) of this behavior.  What I expect to see is that when the Complete button is clicked, the first step is complete, so the icon would change to "10".  However, there is no change, and even when moving to the second step, the icon is "create".  Am I misunderstanding how the `completed` property is supposed to be working, or is there a bug in the Material code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Couple of things wrong here:

> the icon is "create":

The stepper has a dependency on material icons. Adding material-icons to your project and the `'cre'` icon is gone.

Also, the create / edit icon is normal behavior for a completed step. If you like the step to be marked as done you have to set `completed=true` and `editable = false`

Another issue is the use of `let-index="index"`. There is nothing in the [V5 docs](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepperIcon) on this. (And your stackblitz is using V5).

If you have the possibility to upgrade to V6, then it's possible to what you're asking. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stepper-custom-icons?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for this behaviour.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatHorizontalStepper } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild(MatHorizontalStepper) stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;

  complete() {
      this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
      this.stepper.selected.editable = false;
      this.stepper.next();
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear id="stepper">

  <ng-template matStepperIcon="done" let-index="index">
    {{(index+1) * 10}}
  </ng-template>

  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <button mat-button (click)="complete()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Complete</button>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step label="Step 2">
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    <button mat-button (click)="complete()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Complete</button>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step label="Step 3">
    <h3>Step 3</h3>
    <button mat-button (click)="complete()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Complete</button>
  </mat-step>

</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following the (selectionChange) to your mat-stepper:

```
<mat-stepper headerPosition="bottom" color="accent" [linear]="true" [disableRipple]="true" (selectionChange)="onStepChange($event)" #stepper>
```

Also, reference your steps like so:

```
<mat-step #step1></mat-step>
<mat-step #step1></mat-step>
```

Afterwards, in your script:

```
// imports:
import { MatStep } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { StepperSelectionEvent } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

  // in the class:
  @ViewChild('step1') step1: MatStep;
  @ViewChild('step2') step2: MatStep;

  // and create yourself the following function:
  onStepChange(event: StepperSelectionEvent) {
    if (event.selectedIndex === 2) {
      // When moving to Step 3, complete and make un-editable Step 1 and Step 2
      this.step1.completed = true;
      this.step1.editable = false;
      this.step2.completed = true;
      this.step2.editable = false;
    }
  }
```

This will prevent the stepper from going back to steps 1 and 2.