# Using the ChangeDetectorRef to detect component state changes in order to step with the material stepper?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Within the Angular 8 Material Stepper I'm checking some form state and if it passes, then I set `stepCompleted` to true.

Here's a Stackblitz that demos this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-with-fields?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The problem is that Angular does not pick up on the change right away, therefore we have to click next twice.  On the second click it will see the state change.

Also if we navigate back to the step and change the parameters such that the step should not proceed, Angular will still allow the step to proceed on first click, because it still sees `stepCompleted` as being true.  It's not false until we navigate back again.

I think the right way to fix this is to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call it like this:

```
stepComplete() {
   //See whether the step is complete
   //if so
   this.stepCompleted = true;
   this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: probably a better way to do it. Using change detector is usually hacky, on par with setting a timeout or resolving a promise to force change detection.  Can't say what the real issue is without seeing more of the set up

Comment: Got the ChangeDetectorRef idea from this article: https://alligator.io/angular/stripe-elements/

Comment: It's a similar concept.  In this case if there is an error, then change detection needs to be triggered manually so that the form displays the error.

Comment: I mean that’s a weird case because they’re using a 3rd party library that isn’t really integrated into angular. So those functions are being called outside of ngZone so change detection isn’t triggering as it should. They could’ve actually implemented this way better using ngZone or with renderer2. Are you integrating a 3rd parry lib or something?

Comment: No just using the angular material stepper.  When next is clicked it triggers a function that sets `stepComplete` to true, but only if a certain condition is met.  However Angular does realize that `stepComplete` has been set to true on the first click.  It realizes it on the second click.

Comment: I’d post the rest of the code. A click should trigger change detection in stepper

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-with-fields?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Also added stackblitz to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `button[matStepperNext]` [triggers navigation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/decddb5e292470095cddc38d6e52fc10c760b193/src/cdk/stepper/stepper-button.ts#L31-L33) before you set `completed` property.

The solution could be using `mousedown|touchstart` event instead of `click`:

```
<button mat-button matStepperNext (mousedown)="toggleStep1Complete()">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-with-fields-cpfysk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Another thoughts is not to use `button[matStepperNext]` directive and trigger navigation manually:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
    ...
    <button mat-button (click)="stepper.selected.completed = true; stepper.next()">Next</button>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-stepper-demo-with-fields-cu8wkc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

See also:

- [Completed property in Angular Material Stepper doesn't seem to work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867430/completed-property-in-angular-material-stepper-doesnt-seem-to-work-as-expected)

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ole another option here is to have the completed property set to a getter of some kind. like `get stepCompleted() { return this.stepForm.valid; }` so that the order of change detection is guaranteed.